# Code in Persistent EHcache docs not working java

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I want to use `EHcache` in my `java` project. They have persistent storage support. I have read the docs
https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/configuration/fast-restart.html and found this code

```java
Configuration cacheManagerConfig = new Configuration()
    .diskStore(new DiskStoreConfiguration()
        .path("/tmp/file.txt"));
CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration()
    .name("my-cache")
    .maxBytesLocalHeap(16, MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES)
    .maxBytesLocalOffHeap(256, MemoryUnit.MEGABYTES)
    .persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP));

cacheManagerConfig.addCache(cacheConfig);

CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(cacheManagerConfig);
Ehcache myCache = cacheManager.getEhcache("my-cache");
```

I have imported the dependency but it shows lots of error. 
Error I got

```
'Configuration' is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Please provide some simple steps to make use of this library. I read the docs but the code doesn't get worked. Help me with some solutions.

Comment: I don't have the full context, but could you give us more details about where you try this config? Is it a Spring Boot project? I'd suggest to firstly get working your ehcache setup, and afterwards try to configure it for persistent storage support. Some blog posts that might help you to get started: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-ehcache or https://www.baeldung.com/ehcache

Comment: Are you using ehcache 3? (the documentation you linked is for version 2.7)

Comment: ehcache 3 version..

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer.

```
    try(PersistentCacheManager persistentCacheManager =
                newCacheManagerBuilder()
                        .with(persistence("/tmp/myProjectCache"))
                        .withCache("test-cache",
                                newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                                        String.class, String.class,
                                        newResourcePoolsBuilder()
                                                .heap(1, EntryUnit.ENTRIES)
                                                .offheap(1, MemoryUnit.MB)
                                                .disk(2, MemoryUnit.MB, true)
                                )
                        ).build(true)) {
        org.ehcache.Cache cache = persistentCacheManager.getCache("test-cache", String.class, String.class);

        cache.put("name1","steven");
        cache.put("name2","prince");

        System.out.println(cache.get("name1"));
        System.out.println(cache.get("name2"));
    }
```